# Folding in VimWiki like in org mode?

Tags: folding, plugin-vimwiki

I moved from org mode to VimWiki. I used to write "logs" like this

```
* 2020-02-04

  FeatureA
    - progress

  Feature B
    - progress
```

The file can get pretty long as you can imagine.

Now with VimWiki I'd have to make this one big list it looks like I can only do that if I do lists (not fold by headers).

Is there a way I can achieve folding of whole sections, not just lists?
I tried enabling folding by indentation but that doesn't let me to fold big sections like that.

Comment: Not an answer, but did you try https://github.com/dhruvasagar/vim-dotoo ? Then maybe you can keep your org-mode files.